# How to efficiently sort a large dataset in Python using Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I've been working on a project that involves managing a large dataset using Pandas DataFrame in Python. However, I'm facing performance issues when sorting the dataset based on specific columns. I've made several attempts to optimize the sorting process, but I'm still not satisfied with the results.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Initially, I used the `sort_values()` function in Pandas to perform the sorting. However, it was quite slow on the large dataset, taking a significant amount of time to complete.

```py
df.sort_values('column_name', inplace=True)
```

2. Then, I tried using the `nlargest()` function to sort the dataset based on a specific column. This improved the performance slightly, but I'm still looking for a more efficient solution.

```py
df = df.nlargest(n=df.shape[0], columns='column_name')
```

3. I also attempted to use the `numpy.argsort()` function to obtain the sorted indices of the column and then re-arrange the DataFrame accordingly. While this method was faster than the previous ones, it consumed a lot of memory due to the creation of intermediate arrays.

```py
sorted_indices = np.argsort(df['column_name'])
df = df.iloc[sorted_indices]
```

Despite these efforts, I'm keen to find a more optimized way of sorting the large dataset efficiently. Is there a better approach or any other techniques that I could leverage to enhance the sorting performance without compromising the reliability of the results?

Comment: Can you provide the actual DataFrame (or part of it)? And how would you use it? As far as I know, there are no generic, faster sorting methods, but there may be alternatives for some specific data or usage.

Comment: If you are sorting objects or string (likely), then this will be slow. If you are sorting short/small integers/float, the default algorithm can be improved but this is certainly pretty hard to beat it for non-skilled developers. For large integer, the default algorithm should be already pretty fast already compared to the state of the art.